# Obtaining $httpBackend in QUnit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, qunit

I am writing **QUnit** tests for an **Angular** controller. In the setup function of module, I have written the following statements to get an object of **$httpBackend**:

```
 var injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
 var httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');
```

In a test, a mock response for GET is configured as follows:

```
httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond([]);
```

The test spec fails at this statement with error: Object doesn't support property or method `expectGET`

I am able to get other objects like controller, scope injected using the same injector reference.

Did I miss anything here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked [Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott) about this issue and he replied me with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77yVz/1/) that solves the issue. He stated that the following decorator is essential when we use $httpBackend or any other mock defined in angular-mocks.js in QUnit tests:

```
$provide.decorator('$httpBackend', angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
```

I used this approach in a sample application and blogged my learning: http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2013/06/UnitTestingAngularJsControllerUsingQUnitAndSinon.html

Answer (score 1):

You must setup angular to use the **$httpBackend** from [angular-mocks.js](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks)
Which contains the `expectGET` method.

But according to [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.module) it's "**Only available with jasmine.**"