# unit testing Scope of directive whose been injected into another scope

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, sinon

I have a module in angular Called main and in this module I m injecting another module "app-directive" this module has all my directives .

I am doing unit testing on the main module using jasmine and sinon.

In my app-directive mod i have a directive called ckeditor and i am able to call all the methods from the scope of main module but when i m doing unit testing i m getting error."Method does not exists"

I include all the files necessary

am i missing something?

Comment: please include some code in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtaining $httpBackend in QUnit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300485/obtaining-httpbackend-in-qunit-tests)